# Rails 4 - Convert string to time format unless already correct format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I am trying to figure out how to convert a string to a time format only if it isn't already in the correct format.

My current setup:

I have a before save callback

```
before_save :format_time 

def format_time
  self.from_time = from_time.to_time.strftime("%H %M")
  self.to_time   = to_time.to_time.strftime("%H %M")
end
```

that is formatting two strings the user enters into a time.

If the user enters `2:00 PM` the callback will save it as `14 00`

The problem is if a user updates the model, the callback will turn `14 00` into `00 00`

Hence, I want to check if the format is already how it should be. Not sure the best way to go about this. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
before_save :format_time 

def format_time
  self.from_time = sanitize_time( from_time )
  self.to_time   = sanitize_time( to_time )
end

def sanitize_time( time_str )
  begin
    DateTime.strptime(time_str, '%H %M') # will raise ArgumentError if not in '%H %M' format
    time_str
  rescue ArgumentError
    time_str.to_time.strftime("%H %M")
  end
end
```